# Android Lollipop issues with text color

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme, textcolor

I have an app with `android:Theme.Holo`, navigation bar with black background and white textcolor for Button/TextView. It's fine on OS before Lollipop.

In Lollipop I can't see text, I suppose it's black too because, as I said, on previous OS it works fine.

Any well-known issues about text color in Android L?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue recently after upgrading my targetApi from 20 to 22. I have a button with textColor: white, but it was showing transparent because my background color was transparent

I am not sure why the textColor has issues on Lollipop, but I solved it by setting the textColor programmatically.

```
    loginBT = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.beta_login);
    loginBT.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```